# how to access sqlite database from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my application i uploaded sqlite database on the server.
problem is that i have no knowledge how to access the database from the server in my application.

Please tell me anyone how i access database from the server.

Comment: 38 questions and not a single accepted answer....

Answer (score 0):

Since SQLite is a flat file database, there's no way to access it via server (because it doesn't have one duhhh).
Best approach would be either by downloading the database into your sandbox and opening it from there. Or create a simple API to manipulate the database via PHP for example.